# Having iPhone & iPad Perform Different Actions

Tags: iphone, webview, detection

I want the WebView to display a specific URL based on the device the user is using. For example:

```
if(deviceType == iPad)
{
     // Load Site on iPad & Retina iPad
     [webView loadRequest:[URLWithString:@"http://site.com/ipad.html"]];
}
else
{
    // Load Site on iPhone & Retina iPhone
    [webView loadRequest:[URLWithString:@"http://site.com/iphone.html"]];
}
```

How would I go about doing this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```

`UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` is a macro that calls the [`userInterfaceIdiom` method of `UIDevice`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/userInterfaceIdiom), with a fallback if that method isn't available.